# Agendar consulta medica mysql

Tags: mysql

necesito establecer una consulta que me permite determinar si es posible tomar una hora siguiendo las siguintes reglas:

> -un doctor no puede atender en 2 sucursales al mismo horario
>
> -los doctores no pueden utilizar el mismo box de una sucursal en el mismo horario

mi tabla hora es la siguinte:

```
TABLA HORA(
    int id,
    int codmedico, //llave foranea
    int codsucursal, //llave foranea
    int box,
    boolean disponible, //1 disponible para agendar, 0 agendada 
    varchar dia,
    varchar hora
)
```

en la consulta le entrego codmedico,codsucursal,box,dia y hora, pero
intente hacerlo con un procediminto almacenado y no supe como verificar si un doctor ya tenia agendada una hora en algun otra sucursal

### --------------------------------------------------

**edit**: tome en cuenta las acotaciones que me hicieron y cambie la estructura de la tabla dejandola de la siguiente manera:

```
TABLA HORA(
        int id,
        int codmedico, //llave foranea
        int codsucursal, //llave foranea
        int box,
        boolean disponible, //1 disponible para agendar, 0 agendada (en cualquier caso la hora no esta disponible para que se haga el insert)
        datetime fecha;
    )
```

intente con la siguiente query, pero esta no valida lo que necesito:

```
SELECT IFNULL((select Case when disponible=1 then 'no disponible' when disponible=0 then 'no disponible' else 'disponible' end as disponible from hora WHERE fecha='2019-12-17 11:00:00' and box =12 and codSucursal=1),'disponible') as disponible
```

ya que si cambio el box y codsucursal me entrega disponible, a pesar que haya registrada una hora en otro box y sucursal a la misma hora

Comment: Me parece le harían falta columnas s esa tabla, pues con día solo validamos si es lunes, martes, etc pero y la fecha?, Por qué puede que sea mismo día es decir lunes pero en fechas distintas, lo cual ya haría más fácil saber si ese día de la semana y en ese fecha está ocupado

Comment: A parte que para fechas o tiempos el usar varchar no es lo adecuado

Comment: en dia guardo la fecha en formato dd/mm/yy y con STR_TO_DATE(dia, '%d/%c/%Y') transformo de forma rapida el campo a date

Comment: Empiezas mal con tu diseño, las columnas `dia` y `hora` son redundantes, deberías cambiarlas por una columna de tipo `DATETIME`. A partir de ahí podrás facilitar las cosas y no desperdiciar tanto espacio y esfuerzo. Tampoco entiendo mucho para qué sirve la columna `disponible` ¿? Espero que no estés tratando de meter la lógica del programa en la BD.

Comment: la columna disponible me permite determinar si las horas de atención fueron reservadas por un paciente o  aun esta disponible su reserva, asi evito el delete de la hora en caso de que un paciente la agende

Comment: Si tienes una columna`disponible`, eso quiere decir que vas a tener que generar todos los turnos para todos los días, ¿esa es tu idea? y por otro lado los turnos son siempre de 1 hora, ¿no pueden ser parciales? ¿no te convendría más manejar una fecha desde/hasta?

Comment: si, la idea es agregar todas las horas que se realizaran consultas, tengo otra tabla donde tomo el id de esta tabla y algunas otras para agendar la hora, cuando tomo el id, tengo un procedimiento almacenado que cambia el estado de disponible a 0 cuando hago el insert en la otra tabla, respecto al tiempo de consulta por paciente, siempre sera de 1 hora, donde el inicio va de 10 a 20 hrs (la idea es que la ultima hora disponible sea a las 19), las cuales manejo en la tabla sucursal con la hora de apertura y cierre de cada sucursal

Comment: ¿Tan necesario es que sea a nivel de base de datos? Personalmente creo que iría mejor en las reglas de negocio. Hay mayor facilidad, también le puedes hacer pruebas unitarias sin necesidad de conectarte a la base de datos para ello.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lo solucione creando un procedimiento que hace 2 select verificando ambas condiciones

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ConsultarDisponibilidad`(IN `codMedico` INT, IN `box` INT, IN `codSucursal` INT, IN `fecha` VARCHAR(50), OUT `disponibilidad` VARCHAR(50))
consulta:BEGIN 

set @d1 := (select ifnull((select case WHEN h.disponible=1 then "no disponible" when h.disponible=0 then "no disponible" else "disponible" end as disponibilidad from hora h
inner join hora a on a.id=h.id 
where h.fecha=fecha and a.codMedico=codMedico limit 1),"disponible") as disponibilidad);

SET @d2 := (select ifnull((SELECT case when h.disponible=1 THEN "no disponible" when h.disponible=0 then "no disponible" else "disponible" end as disponibilidad from hora h WHERE h.fecha=fecha and h.box=box and h.codSucursal=codSucursal limit 1),"disponible") as disponibilidad);

IF (@d1="no disponible")then begin set disponibilidad='hora no disponible 1'; ROLLBACK;SELECT disponibilidad; leave consulta; end;
end if;

IF (@d2="no disponible")then begin set disponibilidad='hora no disponible 2'; ROLLBACK;SELECT disponibilidad; leave consulta; end;
ELSE set disponibilidad="disponible";
end if;

SELECT disponibilidad;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

la primera variable verifica si el medico tiene disponibilidad agendada previamente, en el caso que si indica que no se puede agregar una nueva disponibilidad a esa hora.

la segunda variable verifica que si el medico no tenia agregada la disponibilidad, pueda tomar el box en la sucursal especificada.

Answer (score 14):

Según lo que veo, tu problema no es tan difícil de resolver como lo parece, por lo tanto no pienses en soluciones complejas, si no en soluciones funcionales. Acabo de simular todo en SQL Server (sé que la respuesta la buscas en MYSQL, pero la lógica es la misma) y estos son los resultados que tengo para ti:

1.- Crear modelo de datos acorde al problema propuesto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde:

- SCHEDULE es la cita médica
- SCHEDULE solo registra el ID del BOX (ya que el box es el que pertenece a la sucursal), junto con el ID del Médico

2.- Poblar las tablas con datos para realizar pruebas simples:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- Grabar datos en SCHEDULE

```
INSERT INTO SCHEDULE (IDREG_BOX,IDREG_MEDICO,HORA_AGENDADA,FECHA_AGENDADA) VALUES (4,1,'15:00',GETDATE())
```

> Una vez insertados los datos, se nos hace fácil validar si es que X Médico tiene una hora tomada en algún box con el mismo día y fecha, ya que podemos hacer un SELECT simple para ello.

Para validar estos datos antes de ingresarlos a la base de datos, tienes 2 opciones

1. Crear un Store Procedure que reciba como argumento el IDREG_MEDICO, HORA_AGENDADA, FECHA_AGENDADA y IDREG_BOX (Todo esto para realizar la comprobación)
2. Validar con tu lenguaje de Back Preferido.

**Por ejemplo...**
¿Como puedes saber si el médico tiene una hora ya tomada?

```
SELECT * FROM SCHEDULE WHERE IDREG_MEDICO = 1 AND HORA_AGENDADA = '15:00' AND FECHA_AGENDADA = '2019-12-18'
```

Si la consulta entrega resultados, es porque el médico ya tiene agendada una hora.

Así no te complicas con soluciones complejas y pones en practica los fundamentos de SQL. 
Recuerda que cada una de las consultas deben ser optimizadas, ya que en ningún caso se debe usar * para hacer los selects.

Espero haber servido de ayuda. Un abrazo y coméntame cualquier cosa.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no resuelve el problema, ya que si otro medico tiene agendada una hora, el select solo valida si ese doctor tiene una hora agendada y no si algun doctor ya la agendo, para mi primero habria que obtener todas las horas agendas con la fecha que uno le entregue y al resultado de esa consulta verificar si esta el medico, si no esta, verificar que el box y la sucursal esten disponibles a esa hora y fecha

Comment: Teniendo toda esa estructura en la base de datos, puedes hacer el select que necesites según tus propios criterios de forma mucho más fácil. El select final que dejé es solo un ejemplo de como hacer las consultas para validar (por ejemplo) si el médico tenía agendada una hora. Puedes realizar la misma consulta de select, por box, o por horas, o por médico, etc... es según tus propios requerimientos. La base de esto es crear bien la estructura para que puedas consultar de forma fácil.

Comment: También puedes generar consultas separadas y combinar los resultados si es que te dificulta el proceso...

Comment: SELECT * FROM SCHEDULES where IDREG_BOX = 'box a consultar' and FECHA_AGENDADA = 'fecha' AND HORA_AGENDADA = 'hora'

Ese es el ejemplo de como podrías ver si un box está ocupado o desocupado en la hora que seleccionas.

Comment: @zhet si te detienes a analizarla bien, esta es una buena opción para resolver tu problema. Otra cosa que tienes que pensar es que en un futuro el contexto puede evolucionar. Imagina que dentro de unos meses se requieren otro tipo de informes, abren sucursales nuevas, se modifican las franjas horarias, abren en otros países, etc y se requieren informes del tipo: *cuantas horas consultó el médico `X` en los días miércoles en la sucursal `Y`*  ... si no tienes un modelo de datos flexible, cualquier evolución en los requerimientos va a ser un verdadero dolor de cabeza.

Answer (score 6):

Sugiero que leas detenidamente las recomendaciones, tu tabla no esta bien enfocada, no estas siguiendo buenas practicas de diseño (lee detenidamente el diseño de la respuesta anterior), si algo cambia en tus reglas de negocio tus consultas cambiarían tanto que después tendrías que rehacer muchas cosas, pero en fin, parece que no puedes cambiar mucho tu diseño o decidiste seguir con tu diseño inicial por lo que te recomiendo que no te compliques tanto con un procedimiento almacenado o que lo simplifiques con un solo query, sugeriría una consulta como la siguiente:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN encontrados > 0 THEN 'No disponible' ELSE 'Disponible' END 
FROM
(
    SELECT count(id) AS encontrados 
    FROM hora 
    WHERE 
        (extract(HOUR FROM hora) = extract(HOUR FROM :hora) AND codmedico = :codmecio) OR
        (extract(HOUR FROM hora) = extract(HOUR FROM :hora) AND codsucursal = :sucursal AND box AND disponible = false)
) AS DISPONIBLE
```